# Rails_admin dont work in production

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, rails-admin, production

I got some problems with my `rails_admin` gem in the production when I trying make first user admin in Rails console.
In the development all works fine. Look at the error and code.

Error terminal:

```
2.3.0 :001 > u = User.first
ActiveRecord::NoDatabaseError: FATAL:  database "myApp_development" does not exist
```

database.production.yml

```
default: &default
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: UTF-8
  pool: 5

development:
  <<: *default
  database: myApp_development
  username: deployer
  password: password

test:
  <<: *default
  database: myApp_test
  username: deployer
  password: password

production:
  <<: *default
  database: myApp_production
  username: deployer
  password: password
```

Comment: How is you launch your _production_ server?

Comment: $ ssh deployer@*********. log in.

Comment: This is the command to connect by `ssh`, how is you launch your _rails production web server_?

Comment: For deploy im using capistrano and nginx - cap production deploy

Comment: This is a deploy process, _how is you run Rails Web Server in production environment_ ? Which  command you(or capistrano) use for run web server on the remote server? Do you launch the Rails console with `bundle exec rails console production` or just `bundle exec rails console`?

Comment: oh...i hit just 'rails c'. Try 'bundle exec rails console production' ?

Comment: To run rails console in the production environment you should use `bundle exec rails console production` or `bundle exec rails console RAILS_ENV=production`, the command `bundle exec rails console` run console in the development env by default.

Comment: It's work! Thanks you so much !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To run rails console in the `production` environment you should use `bundle exec rails console production` or `bundle exec rails console RAILS_ENV=production`, the command `bundle exec rails console` run console in the `development` env by default.

Comment: @VladyslavKalyuzhnyy my pleasure, dont forget upvote the answer, hit ▲

Answer (score 1):

Create the database table and do

`rake db:migrate RAILS_ENV=production`

`rails console RAILS_ENV=production`

Comment: hit this on the vps server?